# What is the maximum size of a column of custom data type in Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, user-defined-types

I'm creating a custom data type in `Postgresql`. The column of this type is going to hold enormous amount of data in each row and the data will increase over time. If you know about the custom types in Postgresql, then you must also know that we have to specify *internal length* as variable in the create type statement if the type's size can't be determined beforehand. I have done the same for my type. So, if I create a column of this data type, how much data can be possibly stored in the column of a single row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field Size: 1GB

> TOASTed fields can be at most 1 GB.

This comes straight from [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-intro.html).

Comment: This is true, but where exactly did you find that quote?

Comment: Got this one from the following pdf: '"PostgreSQL database limits" found here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4302-0018-5%2F1.pdf

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing it with a quote from the official documentation.

Comment: So, you mean any type in postgres, whether custom or inbuilt is limited to store data upto 1 GB. Such limitation is applicable to bytea as well but size can go upto 4 TB for bytea. So, what happens if I try to store a media file in bytea column using lo_import but the media file is so large that the resultant large object to be stored in database exceeds 4TB size ?